# Testing @Scheduled in spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, scheduler

Spring offers the possibility to schedule and execute tasks at specific intervals using annotations, e.g. [`@Scheduled`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html)

Is there a convenient way to unit test this behavior?

Of course I could call the method of the bean myself, but I want to make sure I don't run into problems like [multiple executions due to misconfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242310/java-spring-scheduled-tasks-executing-twice) and so on.

Other frameworks offer the possibility to fast forward the time yourself. One example is [Activiti](http://www.activiti.org/) where you can call

```
org.activiti.engine.impl.util.ClockUtil.setCurrentTime(date)
```

to fast forward the time used by the framework.

Is there something comparable in Spring?

Essentially what I want to do is something like this in a unit test (run using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`)

```
@Test public void testTaskScheduling() {

  assertThat(someOtherBean.getSomeProperty(), is(equalTo(whatIinitiallyExpect)));

  SpringClockUtil.setDate(dateInTwoHours)// This is what I am missing
  SpringTaskExecutor.executeAllScheduledTasks() // Also missing

  assertThat(someOtherBean.getSomeProperty(), is(equalTo(whatIexpectNow)));
}
```

Answer (score 47):

You can test the actual method execution using the regular JUnit, but to test if the `@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")` you specified is correct you can use:

```
@Test
public void testScheduler(){
    // to test if a cron expression runs only from Monday to Friday
    org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger trigger = 
                                      new CronTrigger("0 0 1 * * MON-FRI");
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss EEEE"); 
    final Date yesterday = today.getTime();
    log.info("Yesterday was : " + df.format(yesterday));
    Date nextExecutionTime = trigger.nextExecutionTime(
        new TriggerContext() {

            @Override
            public Date lastScheduledExecutionTime() {
                return yesterday;
            }

            @Override
            public Date lastActualExecutionTime() {
                return yesterday;
            }

            @Override
            public Date lastCompletionTime() {
                return yesterday;
            }
        });

    String message = "Next Execution date: " + df.format(nextExecutionTime);
    log.info(message);

}
```

Here is the output:

```
Yesterday was : 2015/11/06 11:41:58 Friday

Next Execution date: 2015/11/09 01:00:00 Monday
```

As the last execution (set in the `TriggerContext`) was a Friday, the next execution will be on the following Monday.

I was fiddling with the Spring api and I found this solution, I hope this helps somebody as it helped me.

Answer (score -1):

Test the scheduled code by invoking the bean directly.

Then test the scheduling configuration by:

1) deploying your code in a test environment, letting it run for a while and inspecting logs and/or results (assuming the scheduled code does some logging and/or produces visible results) afterwards.

or

2) externalizing the scheduling configuration in Spring XML config using the `<task: />` namespace and injecting a unit test-specific interval/schedule (preferably short and frequent to be usable in a unit/integration test) using `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`. Then in your test verify that the scheduled code (be it mocked or the real thing) was invoked the proper number of times in the given (short) amount of time.