# Spring-boot @Scheduled junit test case

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-scheduled

In `spring-boot` I am using `@EnableScheduling` and have some methods annotated with `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=some interval)`. How I can write test case that check that methods annotated with `@Scheduled` are getting invoked at interval specified in `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=some interval)`. Is there any method in `junit` using which I can write testcase that check working of @Scheduled.

Comment: I just answered similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319640/how-to-test-spring-scheduled/49930983#49930983 Check it out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test Spring @Scheduled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319640/how-to-test-spring-scheduled)