# Testing Java Spring @Scheduled functionality

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got scheduler with cron as follows:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * *")
@SchedulerLock(name = "PT20M")
public void schedulerSubscriptionsUpdate() {}
```

I'm trying to test entire functionality of this scheduled method - some kind of an integration test (including correctness of method's execution - time).
Do you have any sugestions how can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test Spring @Scheduled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319640/how-to-test-spring-scheduled)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-scheduled-annotation

Comment: @nodlaw did you solve the test?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Awaility library which provides for this purpose:

Add that library with maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
    <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

We can use the Awaitility DSL to make our test more declarative, Something like:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(ScheduledConfig.class)
public class ScheduledAwaitilityIntegrationTest {

    @SpyBean
    private Counter counter;

    @Test
    public void whenWaitOneSecond_thenScheduledIsCalledAtLeastTenTimes() {
        await()
          .atMost(Duration.ONE_SECOND)
          .untilAsserted(() -> verify(counter, atLeast(10)).scheduled());
    }
}
```

Source - baeldung.com/spring-testing-scheduled-annotation

Comment: This is copy and paste from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-scheduled-annotation

Comment: @elmigue017 - Its our bad that sometimes we have to do this,

Comment: @elmigue017 - added source in answer