# Some doubts about this Spring Batch @Scheduled() annotation and how to manually start a Spring Batch job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, spring-batch

I am pretty new in Spring Batch and I have the following doubts about how to schedule the job start at a specific time.

Into my project I have this **SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher** class:

```
@Component
public class SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher.class);

    private final Job job;
    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private ExecutionContext executionContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher(@Qualifier("updateNotaryDistrictsJob") Job job, 
                                         JobLauncher jobLauncher,
                                         ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        this.job = job;
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        this.executionContext = executionContext;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * *")
    public void runSpringBatchExampleJob() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        LOGGER.info("Spring Batch example job was started");
        
        List<NotaryDistrict> notaryDistrictsList = new ArrayList<NotaryDistrict>();
        executionContext.put("notaryDistrictsList", notaryDistrictsList);
        
        jobLauncher.run(job, newExecution());

        LOGGER.info("Spring Batch example job was stopped");
    }

    private JobParameters newExecution() {
        Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();

        JobParameter parameter = new JobParameter(new Date());
        parameters.put("currentTime", parameter);

        return new JobParameters(parameters);
    }
}
```

As you can see it contains the **runSpringBatchExampleJob()** method running the job at a specific time set by the cron expression into the **Scheduled** annotation:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * *")
public void  throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
```

What is the exact meaniong of this CRON exception: it seems to me that the job is runned every 10 seconds but maybe I am wrong. How can I change this CRON expression in order to perform my job every night at 01:00 AM?

Another doubt is: at the moment I have this empty JUnit test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
class UpdateInfoBatchApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Is it possible to run my job directly from a JUnit class? I know that this should not be a proper unit test (maybe more an integration test) but I also want to test my entire job without depending on the time set in the CRON exception running a JUnit test method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring cron job at every 1:00 am:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * ?")
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32521238/9391162) for the difference between Linux and Spring in terms of writing cron jobs.

For testing cron jobs check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32319640/9391162). You need to test your own code.

In addition, you can use [Awaitility](https://www.baeldung.com/awaitlity-testing) library.