# Why java scheduled function doesn't get triggered by changing system time?

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

I have a function annotated with `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 22 ? * *")`, means it will be executed every day at 10:00 p.m. I want to test that function manually and so I am changing system time manually just before 10:00 p.m hoping function will be executed when clock reaches 10:00 p.m. But function didn't get executed. Why? Doesn't `@Scheduled` depend on system time?

Comment: I assume this is Spring? Have you put @EnableScheduling in your spring configuration class?

Comment: Yes, @Scheduled is spring annotation.

Comment: If the process is already running when you change the time, I *believe* this will not cause a re-evaluation of the cron specification. So you'll need to change the time before running the process. Or, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327956/testing-scheduled-in-spring.

Comment: ok, Have you put @EnableScheduling in your spring configuration class?

Comment: Is it enterprise environment with multiple users logged in at the same time ?

Comment: Your SpringApplication class needs @EnableScheduling annotation.

Comment: @Schedule doesn't depent on system time. By default the time for cron job is taken from jvm i.e. java.util.date. So instead of changing system time try changing the cron job time to test the system.

Comment: Because it isn't scheduled at that exact time. Each scheduling recalculates the delay  needed to launch the next one. It isn't really a time based triggered.

Comment: @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 22 ? * *") allow your system to  trigger the method when ever the system clock reach 10:00 pm , no matter if you change the time at middle. Only thing you might missing is  @EnableScheduling.