# Spring Boot @Scheduled running twise

Tags: spring-boot

I have a scheduler which runs everyday once at 8.01pm. But i would seem that when it runs at 8.01pm it run twice. Following is my code

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 1 20 * * *")     
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        logger.info("started");
    }
```

Can anyone help me to fix my problem.Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the bean is created only once in your app?

Comment: yes. bean is created only once.

Comment: Shouldn't your cron expression be `0 0 20 * * ?`

Comment: i'm running at 8.01 pm. sorry about that. I will edit the question

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242310/java-spring-scheduled-tasks-executing-twice ? Answers include all sorts of misconfiguration possible.

Comment: How's your class annotated?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle i have checked that allso

Comment: @MarkusG. I'm using Component for annotating the class

Comment: Is your context loaded twice? (look in the logs) Try to delete and make a new Component with the Scheduled Task, what if you dont use a cron-job and try with a fixed rate? If it also executes twice it could be a bug in your spring version? Show us the logs

Comment: @MarkusG. Thanks Markus. Context was loading twise was the issue.

Comment: This seems to be duplicated, please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242310/java-spring-scheduled-tasks-executing-twice