# cron scheduler getting called twice on scheduled time of schecduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cron

**This is the bean code for cron scheduler. declaration for runMeTask And runMeJob**

```
<bean id="runMeTask" class="com.ascent.fieldomobify.cornScheduler.RunMeTask"/>
<bean name="runMeJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.ascent.fieldomobify.cornScheduler.RunMeJob" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="runMeTask" value-ref="runMeTask" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 13 * * ?" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

it get call directly from bean scheduler configuration
**The first class is RunMeJob**

```
public class RunMeJob extends QuartzJobBean {
private RunMeTask runMeTask;

public void setRunMeTask(RunMeTask runMeTask) {
    this.runMeTask = runMeTask;
  }

protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
    throws JobExecutionException {

    try {
        runMeTask.printMe();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

form here i call the controller's method which is having the logic
**Second class RunMeTask**

```
public class RunMeTask{
@Autowired
WorkOrderController workorderContoller; 

public void setWorkorderContoller(WorkOrderController workorderContoller) {
    this.workorderContoller = workorderContoller;
  }


public void printMe() throws ParseException {
    workorderContoller.printSysOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please help me out regarding this.

Comment: Not able to see the bean declaration for runMeJob. Please update it

Comment: Updated please help......!!!

Comment: Looks fine to me. I would recommend you to use one approach either use XML to wire your beans or use Annotations only. But never mix them

Comment: can you help me exactly what i need to do
cron scheduler call 2 times to my function sometime not each time.

Comment: The only reason it is called twice is that the method is being called twice. There may be two schedulers running at the specified time. Try debugging quartz.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171337/discussion-between-yati-sawhney-and-prashant).

Comment: Please refer this link : <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242310/java-spring-scheduled-tasks-executing-twice>

Answer (score 0):

there are some scenarios where you can get that behavior, please check this thread: [Java Spring @Scheduled tasks executing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242310/java-spring-scheduled-tasks-executing-twice)