# Spring @Scheduled executing the job twice than the expected number of times

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run some job in my Spring MVC application periodically. Based on tutorials online I set up the Scheduled Job as follows:

Here is the AppInitializer (I have no setup in the XMLs):

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
        rootContext.register(JPAConfiguration.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(MvcConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }
}
```

Here is the configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.prime.tutorials"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.prime.tutorials.model", "com.prime.tutorials.repository"})
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Value("${jdbcURL}")
    private transient String jdbcURL;

    @Value("${dbPassword}")
    private transient String dbPassword;

    /* The usual stuff here, let me know if you want me post that as well */


}
```

This is the class handling the Scheduled job:

```
@Service
public class ScheduledJobService {

    @Autowired
    private PrimeRepository primeRepository

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixedDelay.in.milliseconds:10000}")
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Current time is :: " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }

}
```

As you can see the fixed delay is set to 10 secs but my job is running every 5 seconds. I am not able to understand why this is happening. I went through the questions posted in regards to this topic before but I havent been able to find a matching solution.

Other posts suggest that in such cases the beans might be getting initialized twice but based on my config I am not sure how that is happening.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242310/java-spring-scheduled-tasks-executing-twice)
This question above seems like an exact duplicate of the what I am asking but the OP hasnt posted his/her configuration or setup. Most of the answers suggest double initialization of the components which I am not sure is the case with my application.

```
Current time is :: Sun Jun 10 22:53:16 EDT 2018
Current time is :: Sun Jun 10 22:53:22 EDT 2018
Current time is :: Sun Jun 10 22:53:26 EDT 2018
Current time is :: Sun Jun 10 22:53:32 EDT 2018
Current time is :: Sun Jun 10 22:53:36 EDT 2018
```

**EDIT-1**

Based on suggestion from Jennifer I do see that two instances are calling the run method.

**EDIT-2**

M.Deinum's guess was absolutely right, my MvcConfig.java was annotated by @ComponentScan which made the Schedule Job run twice. But after removing that annotation from the MvcConfig.java my end-points stopped working. What am I missing here..

Comment: declare `fixedDelay.in.milliseconds` in application.properties

Comment: @JohnJoe Its already in properties. 10000 is a default value.

Comment: Let me guess... The `MvcConfig` also has a `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.prime.tutorials"})`.

Comment: @M.Deinum My bad, that was absolutely right. Removing that annotation actually made the scheduled job execute at the right frequency but my end-points stopped working. Is there a way out and should I post another question or edit the existing one?

Comment: Your `MvcConfig` should only detect web related components. Currently it detects everything and you are basically loading your whole application twice (I suspect it will also detect the `JPAConfiguration`). You should disable the default filters and add an include filter for `@Controller` and `@ControllerAdvice` and in your root context you should exclude the `@Controller` and `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am not sure what you mean by 'disable the default filters' But if I understand correctly, should I just scan 'com.prime.tutorials.controller' package in the MvcConfig.java and rest of the packages in JPAConfiguration.java

Comment: No... You want to disable the detection of certain components... (Also technical separation is a wrong way to split things imho). You can set `useDefaultFilters` to `false` on `@ComponentScan` and then also configure `includeFilters` and `excludeFilters`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Now I get it. What you said makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot for your patience and your explanation. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you, probably, have the same component scan in both your `JPAConfiguration` and `MvcConfig`. The result is that you basically are loading your whole application twice (so unless you want to have memory-issues, weird transactional issues etc. that is the way to go).

What you want is that your `ContextLoaderListener` (the root context) loads everything but web related beans and the `DispatcherServlet` should load only web related beans (views, controllers, advices etc.).

The [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) has properties with which you can control this. In the `JPAConfiguration` add some `excludeFilters` on the `MvcConfig` disable the defaults and add some `includeFilters`.

Your `@ComponentScan` for the `JPAConfiguration` should contain the following:

```
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"com.prime.tutorials"},
        excludeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter( { Controller.class, ControllerAdvice.class })
})
```

Your `MvcConfig` you should use the same but as an `includeFilters` instead and disable the default filters.

```
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"com.prime.tutorials"},
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        includeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter( { Controller.class, ControllerAdvice.class })
})
```

You don't want to do different base packages as that would be quite cumbersome. It is also IMHO that you shouldn't use technical separation as a way of creating packages (see also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/258196/java-application-structure-horizontal-vs-vertical-split/258197#258197) .

Answer (score 2):

This typically happens when you create more than one instance of the `Scheduled` class (`ScheduledJobService`). A common cause is that the Spring context is created more than once.

Add this to the run method to see if you have more than one instance:

```
public void run() {
   System.out.println(this + " Current time is :: " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}
```

You will be able to see in the output if its more than one instance.

To make sure its not the property value, try without a hard coded value of 10000.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
```

Comment: Its a good idea but if its two instances, how would I know why dual instances are being created.

Comment: So its confirmed that I have two instances. I see two objects running the same job