# Spring Boot runs scheduled job twice, But it works fine in the local

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, kotlin, spring-scheduled

My Problem is that the scheduled method "subscription" is called twice.

This is the template I use.

https://github.com/JetBrains/gcp-samples/tree/master/google-appengine-sample

When I use `$mvn spring-boot:run` is working fine in local

But I use `$mvn appengine:deploy` scheduled is called twice.

My code:

```
@Component
class ScheduledTasks {
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * *")
    fun subscription() {
            var hasBeenInitialized = false
            val firebaseApps = FirebaseApp.getApps()
            for (app in firebaseApps) {
                if (app.name == FirebaseApp.DEFAULT_APP_NAME) {
                    hasBeenInitialized = true
                }
            }
            if(!hasBeenInitialized) {
                InitializeGCP()
            }

            var db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore()
            val query = db.collection("subscription").get()
            val querySnapshot = query.get()
            val documents = querySnapshot.documents

            for (document in documents) {
                if (localTime.equals(document.getString("time"))) {
                    ...post to my ChatBot Api...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Spring @Scheduled tasks executing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242310/java-spring-scheduled-tasks-executing-twice)

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed this article. Not working for me...

Comment: And... I also want to understand why this problem does not happen in local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check is there any two instance of your server? this cron job will be unique for only one server.

Answer (score 0):

I check my GCP.

I have two instances in the same version.

Is this related?